# bootstrap tabs not showing content

Tags: php

i have an issue with my website. I am using bootstrap tabs to navigate through my site. All tabs are working except the last one. He is mixing the content of the last one with the one before.
I am not a coder so i think my code looks horrible. I copied and pasted from different sites. So if you have improvements please let me know.

[The .... in the red circle should be underneath the planning tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz92i.png)

```html
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Duiklog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<link href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>Welkom bij mijn duiklog</h1> 
 



 


<div> 
<!-- Nav tabs --> 
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"> <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li> 
<li role="presentation"><a href="#Duiklog" aria-controls="Duiklog" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Duiklog</a></li> 
<li role="presentation"><a href="#invoer" aria-controls="invoer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Invoer</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#planning" aria-controls="planning" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Planning</a></li>

</ul> 
<!-- Tab panes --> 
<div class="tab-content"> 
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
<h2>Stats</h2><br>

Aantal duiken: 2<br>
Gemiddeld lucht verbruikt: 22.5000

</div> 
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Duiklog">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Locatie</th>
 <th>Buddy</th>
 <th>Diepte</th>
 <th>Duiktijd</th>
 <th>Watertype</th>
 <th>Zicht</th>
 <th>Temp</th>
 <th>Duiktype</th>
 <th>Fles</th>
 <th>Druk start</th>
 <th>Druk einde</th>
 <th>Druk verbruikt</th>
 <th>Lucht verbruikt</th>
 <th>Opmerkingen</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>2012-05-20</td><td>boschmolenplas</td><td>Harrie Wassen</td><td>11 m </td><td>39 min </td><td>Zoet</td><td>3-6 m </td><td>13 C </td><td>opleiding</td><td>10 l </td><td>200 bar </td><td>10 bar </td><td>190 bar </td><td>23ltr/min </td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2012-05-13</td><td>Panheel</td><td>Harrie Wassen</td><td>9 m </td><td>40 min </td><td>Zoet</td><td>3-6 m </td><td>13 C </td><td>opleiding</td><td>10 l </td><td>210 bar </td><td>40 bar </td><td>170 bar </td><td>22ltr/min </td><td>eerste duik</td></tr></table>
</div> 
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="invoer">
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">


<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="datum">Datum:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="idatum" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="locatie">Locatie:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ilocatie" placeholder="Voer locatie in">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="buddy">Buddy:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ibuddy" placeholder="Voer buddy in">
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="diepte">Diepte:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="idiepte" placeholder="Voer maximale diepte in">
    </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="duiktijd">Duiktijd:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="iduiktijd" placeholder="Voer duiktijd in">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="drukstart">Drukstart:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="idrukstart" placeholder="Voer begindruk in">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="drukeinde">Drukeinde:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="idrukeinde" placeholder="Voer eindedruk in">
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="watertype">Watertype:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control" name="iwatertype">
 <option>Zoet</option>
 <option>Zout</option>
 <option>Brak</option>
    </select>
    </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="zicht">Zicht:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="izicht" placeholder="Voer zicht in">
    </div>
         <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="temperatuur">Temperatuur:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="itemperatuur" placeholder="Voer temperatuur in">
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="duiktype">Duiktype:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iduiktype" placeholder="Voer Duiktype in">
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="flesvolume">Flesvolume:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="iflesvolume" placeholder="Voer flesvolume in">
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="opmerkingen">Opmerkingen:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iopmerkingen" placeholder="Opmerkingen">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div> 
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="planning">
.....
</div>



<div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 75px;">
</div>
<footer class="footer"> 
<div class="container"> 
<p class="text-muted">
Connectie met duiklog
```

Comment: It is likely that you are missing a closing tag somewhere. I would suggest running your HTML through a validator. https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Duiklog</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body> 
<h1>Welkom bij mijn duiklog</h1> 
 



 


<div> 
<!-- Nav tabs --> 
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"> <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li> 
<li role="presentation"><a href="#Duiklog" aria-controls="Duiklog" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Duiklog</a></li> 
<li role="presentation"><a href="#invoer" aria-controls="invoer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Invoer</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#planning" aria-controls="planning" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Planning</a></li>

</ul> 
<!-- Tab panes --> 
<div class="tab-content"> 
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
<h2>Stats</h2><br>

Aantal duiken: 2<br>
Gemiddeld lucht verbruikt: 22.5000

</div> 
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Duiklog">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Locatie</th>
 <th>Buddy</th>
 <th>Diepte</th>
 <th>Duiktijd</th>
 <th>Watertype</th>
 <th>Zicht</th>
 <th>Temp</th>
 <th>Duiktype</th>
 <th>Fles</th>
 <th>Druk start</th>
 <th>Druk einde</th>
 <th>Druk verbruikt</th>
 <th>Lucht verbruikt</th>
 <th>Opmerkingen</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>2012-05-20</td><td>boschmolenplas</td><td>Harrie Wassen</td><td>11 m </td><td>39 min </td><td>Zoet</td><td>3-6 m </td><td>13 C </td><td>opleiding</td><td>10 l </td><td>200 bar </td><td>10 bar </td><td>190 bar </td><td>23ltr/min </td><td></td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2012-05-13</td><td>Panheel</td><td>Harrie Wassen</td><td>9 m </td><td>40 min </td><td>Zoet</td><td>3-6 m </td><td>13 C </td><td>opleiding</td><td>10 l </td><td>210 bar </td><td>40 bar </td><td>170 bar </td><td>22ltr/min </td><td>eerste duik</td></tr></table>
</div> 
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="invoer">
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">
    
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="datum">Datum:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="idatum" >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="locatie">Locatie:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ilocatie" placeholder="Voer locatie in">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="buddy">Buddy:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ibuddy" placeholder="Voer buddy in">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="diepte">Diepte:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="idiepte" placeholder="Voer maximale diepte in">
    </div>
         </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="duiktijd">Duiktijd:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="iduiktijd" placeholder="Voer duiktijd in">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="drukstart">Drukstart:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="number"  class="form-control" name="idrukstart" placeholder="Voer begindruk in">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="drukeinde">Drukeinde:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="idrukeinde" placeholder="Voer eindedruk in">
    </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="watertype">Watertype:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control" name="iwatertype">
 <option>Zoet</option>
 <option>Zout</option>
 <option>Brak</option>
    </select>
    </div>
         </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="zicht">Zicht:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="izicht" placeholder="Voer zicht in">
    </div>
         </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="temperatuur">Temperatuur:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="itemperatuur" placeholder="Voer temperatuur in">
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="duiktype">Duiktype:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iduiktype" placeholder="Voer Duiktype in">
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="flesvolume">Flesvolume:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="iflesvolume" placeholder="Voer flesvolume in">
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="opmerkingen">Opmerkingen:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="iopmerkingen" placeholder="Opmerkingen">
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div> 
</div>
      
</form>
</form>
</div>
    
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="planning">
this is working
</div>
```

Check this code this is working code and for more please follow the link

http://quandaflow.com/category/website/css/

Comment: Thanks that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your html code had a lot of errors, unclosed tags etc.. The following code is the valid version of what you are trying to do:

```
<div>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab"
                                                  data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#Duiklog" aria-controls="Duiklog" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Duiklog</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#invoer" aria-controls="invoer" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Invoer</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#planning" aria-controls="planning" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Planning</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <h2>Stats</h2>
            <br> Aantal duiken: 2
            <br> Gemiddeld lucht verbruikt: 22.5000

        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Duiklog">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Datum</th>
                    <th>Locatie</th>
                    <th>Buddy</th>
                    <th>Diepte</th>
                    <th>Duiktijd</th>
                    <th>Watertype</th>
                    <th>Zicht</th>
                    <th>Temp</th>
                    <th>Duiktype</th>
                    <th>Fles</th>
                    <th>Druk start</th>
                    <th>Druk einde</th>
                    <th>Druk verbruikt</th>
                    <th>Lucht verbruikt</th>
                    <th>Opmerkingen</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>2012-05-20</td>
                    <td>boschmolenplas</td>
                    <td>Harrie Wassen</td>
                    <td>11 m</td>
                    <td>39 min</td>
                    <td>Zoet</td>
                    <td>3-6 m</td>
                    <td>13 C</td>
                    <td>opleiding</td>
                    <td>10 l</td>
                    <td>200 bar</td>
                    <td>10 bar</td>
                    <td>190 bar</td>
                    <td>23ltr/min</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2012-05-13</td>
                    <td>Panheel</td>
                    <td>Harrie Wassen</td>
                    <td>9 m</td>
                    <td>40 min</td>
                    <td>Zoet</td>
                    <td>3-6 m</td>
                    <td>13 C</td>
                    <td>opleiding</td>
                    <td>10 l</td>
                    <td>210 bar</td>
                    <td>40 bar</td>
                    <td>170 bar</td>
                    <td>22ltr/min</td>
                    <td>eerste duik</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="invoer">


            <form action="send_post.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="datum">Datum:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="datum" type="date" class="form-control" name="idatum">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="locatie">Locatie:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="locatie" type="text" class="form-control" name="ilocatie"
                               placeholder="Voer locatie in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="buddy">Buddy:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="buddy" type="text" class="form-control" name="ibuddy" placeholder="Voer buddy in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="diepte">Diepte:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="diepte" type="number" class="form-control" name="idiepte"
                               placeholder="Voer maximale diepte in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="duiktijd">Duiktijd:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="duiktijd" type="number" class="form-control" name="iduiktijd"
                               placeholder="Voer duiktijd in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="drukstart">Drukstart:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="drukstart" type="number" class="form-control" name="idrukstart"
                               placeholder="Voer begindruk in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="drukeinde">Drukeinde:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="drukeinde" type="number" class="form-control" name="idrukeinde"
                               placeholder="Voer eindedruk in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="watertype">Watertype:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select id="watertype" class="form-control" name="iwatertype">
                            <option>Zoet</option>
                            <option>Zout</option>
                            <option>Brak</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="zicht">Zicht:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="zicht" type="text" class="form-control" name="izicht"
                               placeholder="Voer zicht in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2"
                           for="temperatuur">Temperatuur:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="temperatuur" type="number" class="form-control" name="itemperatuur"
                               placeholder="Voer temperatuur in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2"
                           for="duiktype">Duiktype:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="duiktype" type="text" class="form-control" name="iduiktype"
                               placeholder="Voer Duiktype in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="flesvolume">Flesvolume:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="flesvolume" type="number" class="form-control" name="iflesvolume"
                               placeholder="Voer flesvolume in">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2"
                           for="opmerkingen">Opmerkingen:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input id="opmerkingen" type="text" class="form-control"
                               name="iopmerkingen" placeholder="Opmerkingen">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="planning">
            .....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```